# How to data pass from 2 main component to 1 child component

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I have 2 main components and I want to pass data from these components to the child component.

FirstMainComponent is passing data to the ChildComponent

```
@Component({
 ...
  providers: [DialogService]
})
export class FirstMainComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(public dialogService: DialogService){}
...

const dialogRef= this.dialogService.open(ChildComponent, {
  header: 'Something',
  width: '90%',
  baseZIndex: 100000,
  closeOnEscape : true,
  closable : true,
  data: {
    Code: '1001',
    Name:'Something'
}
});
dialogRef.onClose.subscribe((async (childModel: ChildModel) => {
  // my code
}));
}
```

SecondMainComponent is not passing data to the ChildComponent

```
@Component({
     ...
      providers: [DialogService]
    })
export class SecondMainComponent implements OnInit{
constructor(){
    public dialogService: DialogService
}
...
const dialogRef= this.dialogService.open(ChildComponent, {
  header: 'Something',
  width: '90%',
  baseZIndex: 100000,
  autoZIndex: true,
  closeOnEscape: true,
  data: {
    Code: '1002'
  }
});
dialogRefFindCustomers.onClose.subscribe((childModel: ChildModel) => {
  // my code
    }
  }
});
}
```

here is ChildComponent

```
@Component({
  ...
// no providers
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(){
public ref: DynamicDialogRef,
public config: DynamicDialogConfig
}
...
console.log("this.config.data");
console.log(this.config.data);
this.ref.close();
}
```

I am getting this error while passing data from SecondMainComponent to ChildComponent

1. NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[CustomerSearchComponent -> DynamicDialogRef]:
2. TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'instance')

If I change the ChildComponent providers field as follows, FirstMainComponent and SecondMainComponent gets an error.

```
providers: [DynamicDialogRef, DynamicDialogConfig]
```

Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Code')

beacuse `this.config.data` = undefined

Comment: maybe remove DialogService from the components and do:

@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [DialogService, DynamicDialogRef, DynamicDialogConfig],
  ...
})

also how does DialogService look like

Comment: What does `DialogService` looks like specially all the code that is involved in the `.open` method. Also it will quick for you to get the required help if you can create a reproducible demo of the issue you are facing on stackblitz...

Comment: A stackblitz would be helpful to debug this.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use a separate Service in which you set your properties before opening the dialogs.

Doing this, you can access your data easily in your childs.